# How to start a program with command line arguments on Windows' cmd and force it to run foreground?

Tags: java, windows, excel, selenium, command-line

I'm executing a offline smoke test (SELENIUM) and to make it enable the macros in a excel spreadsheet that is generated by the system, I had to use a workaround where in the java code, I open the excel spreadsheet, save and close it, so that I can run the test and write values onto this spreadsheet. To open the excel spreadsheet (I setup excel to trust all macros), I wrote the following java code where I use command line commands to execute it:

```
@Then("Enable Worksheet Macros")
public void enableWorksheetMacros() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {

    final String diretory = "c:\\automation\\";
    final File file = new File(diretory);

    final File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).endsWith(".xls");
        }
    });

    if (files.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("too many files");
    } else if (files.length == 1) {
        final String filename = files[0].getAbsolutePath();

        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", filename);
        final Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        final Robot r = new Robot();

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        Thread.sleep(200);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(200);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

}
```

As you can see, right after opening the excel file, I just press ALT+F4 and press ENTER twice (it closes the file and save it). It was working fine, until I run this code in another environment, where when it opens the excel file, it is running background.

Is there a way I can make sure the program will run foreground?

**EDIT**:
I found this question on SU where the guy has the same problem I do, but no answer until now: https://superuser.com/questions/700879/windows-task-scheduler-starting-excel-in-background-how-to-force-to-start-in-fo

Comment: I added code to maximize excel when it is opened... the last 5 times we ran smoke test it worked.. it's a little bit unstable, so I need more time to be sure it is working.... if so, I'll post an answer here..

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. If it is about writing in an excel spreadsheet using java, you can use the Apache POI (http://poi.apache.org/). IF not, please rephrase your question.

Comment: My question is about finding a way to open excel using java and make sure it will run foreground. I'm using ASPOSE to read/write in excel spreadsheets :)

Comment: This isn't working... :( What we'll do now is to simulate a click on the program(yes.. another workaround) when it opens excel, to try to make sure if it will be running foreground. I can't believe no body has ever found a solution for this before :/